# VLCJ get raw output data

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, outputstream, vlcj

I'm trying to write a java program that acts as a proxy to a VLC(J) stream. The goal is to start a mediaPlayer stream with some simple args to output over RTSP. This already works. What I want to do now is write that raw output data to a socket rather than have a client access the stream directly.

I can't seem to find in the tests a way to capture an outputstream of raw data I can then send through a socket to a client. Is this possible using VLCJ? Is the outputstream of the mediaplayer exposed in a way I can hand it off?

Thanks